# Clone a list of elements to a alert window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications, clone

I have a list of clients created by code below, every client has a link to its destination (its a chat app):

```
$('#clientList').append('<a id="'+i+'" href="#null"><li><div>'+appClient +'</div></li></a>');
```

What i want to do is clone the list possible with its link destinations to a alert window, is there a better way than using JQuery `clone()`?

Comment: A better way? http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Do you just want the following? `alert( $('#clientList').text() );`

Comment: You markup is invalid. `<li>` should be the child element of `<ul>` or `<ol>` elements *only*.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard: I tried clone(), its just cloning the list of objects, nothing else.

Comment: @VisioN Maybe clientList is an ul or ol? Its called a LIST afterall.

Comment: @VisioN, the question is not about the html, as u can see im appending li to clientList, which is ul

Comment: @nihulus what is it that you are trying to achieve here? Because if you want the elements to show as in an alert as they do in your browser it can be usefull to know that it cant be done ;)

Comment: @nihulus You are appending `<a>` elements to `clientList`, *which is `<ul>`*.

Comment: @nihulus VisioN is right, you should open and close the <a> tag IN the <li>

Comment: @Teun Pronk, ok so i have to recreate them in the alert instead cloning

Comment: @nihulus well its not possible to place a div in an alert. Alerts cant contain divs. and if you want to alert all the elements that are in the clientlist use `alert($('#clientList').html());` This will display the contents of your list as text.

Comment: @Teun Pronk , ok, ty for reply, maybe its better just create a popup window which can contain divs

Comment: @nihulus Yeah probably best, just give it the highest z-index in your css. This way it will always be on top of the others ;)